# Make countif ignore "- -" from continue

Tags: google-sheets

I'm having trouble with a countif that I am using to count the number of entries in a range. The problem is that the range is populated with an array formula, and when the data changes the cells the array formula added a `=CONTINUE(...)` to now display `--` (minus minus)

```
=COUNTIF(C6:C, "<>")
```

Is there a way that the countif could be written to ignore cells with `--`?

Comment: please try out the answer below and comment. Btw way I assumed all your search data are texts. Because below wildcard will only consider texts.

Answer (score 1):

The -- is a way that Google Sheets displays the #VALUE! error. So you can use the [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/drive/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=25273&page=table.cs&tab=1240291) function to "mask" any of these errors:

`=ArrayFormula(COUNTIF(IFERROR(C6:C);"<>"))`

or more simply:

`=ArrayFormula(COUNTA(IFERROR(C6:C)))`

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

Why don't you filter out all cells that are not text or similar to --?
Then use filtered range for countif.

`=COUNTIF((ROWS(C6:C)-COUNTIF(C6:C"<>*")) , "ur criteria")`

Is there a way your formula array could cast a string other than --?

Check this [article](http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions04.html)

The search you are doing has regular expression.
Writing this on mobile. So please try out and pardon for weird formatting.